# Unable to make a POST request to OAuth endpoint

Tags: post, google-drive-api

I tried to perform this request but I get errors:

```
1. { "error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "The OAuth client was not found." }
```

After I request it again:

```
2. 405. That’s an error.

The request method omPOST is inappropriate for the URL /oauth2/v4/token. That’s all we know.
```

Details:

```
 POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.googleapis.com
    Content-length: 208
    content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    user-agent: google-oauth-playground

    client_secret=MYSECRET&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=MYTOKEN&client_id=MYCLIENTID
```

EDIT:
I was sending the request to an invalid endpoint, making it unavaiable for me to receive the expected data. I was able to fix it by following the steps in the google docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates your client ID is wrong. Please make sure it's the client ID from the Google API console (console.developers.google.com) and it matches the Client Secret. The refresh token should also be one issued to the original client ID.

Comment: when I resend the request I get this error: The request method omPOST is inappropriate for the URL /oauth2/v4/token. That’s all we know. - If I send a GET request then I get another error.